# How do you declare a const array of function pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, function-pointers

Firstly, I've got functions like this.

```
void func1();
void func2();
void func3();
```

Then I create my typedef for the array:

```
void (*FP)();
```

If I write a normal array of function pointers, it should be something like this:

```
FP array[3] = {&func1, &func2, &func3};
```

I want to make it a constant array, using **const** before "FP", but I've got this error messages:

> error: cannot convert 'void ( * )()' to 'void ( *  const)()' inialization

PD: Sorry my bad English.

EDIT:

**x.h**

```
typedef void (*FP)();

class x
{
 private:
  int number;
  void func1();
  void func2();
  void func3();
  static const FP array[3];
}
```

**x.cpp**

```
const FP x::array[3] = {&x::func1, &x::func2, &x::func3};
```

My code is more large and complex, this is a summary

Comment: Its always better to write the actual code than saying "Then I create my typedef for the array:" or "using const before "FP"".

Comment: @Facon: You are using a class? Could you post the entire code here?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. BTW, which compiler you are using?

Comment: Never mind me. As noticed by @Prasoon, the code is wrong. And the error message is also weird.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Then I create my typedef for the array:
>   `void (*FP)();`

Did you miss `typedef` before `void`?

Following works on my compiler.

```
 void func1(){}
 void func2(){}
 void func3(){}

 typedef void (*FP)();


 int main()
 {
     const FP ar[3]= {&func1, &func2, &func3};
 }
```

---

## EDIT

(after seeing your edits)

**x.h**

```
 class x;
 typedef void (x::*FP)(); // you made a mistake here

 class x
 {
   public:
      void func1();
      void func2();
      void func3();
      static const FP array[3];
 };
```

Comment: I was using a class..., it takes me the same error using const FP array[3] = ... or using FP const array[3] = ...

Comment: Uhh, you got an good eye, great! Given that his error message said `void (*)()`, i was thinking myself of static member functions, not checking whether they really are. Now all the question is - did he miss writing `static`, or did he typo'ed the typedef or/and did he typo'ed the error message? xD

Comment: @Johannes: Yeah, his question before the edits was a bit confusing(because the code had no errors). xD :-)

Comment: Now I've got this error:


x.cpp:line: error: must use .* or ->* to call pointer-to-member function in 'x::array[((int)((x*)this)->x::number)] (...)'


Calling the array in another x class method.


How do you call it?

Comment: @PrasoonSaurav Highlighting the method to access a function from the array would complete the post.

Answer (score 10):

without `typedef`:

```
void (*const fp[])() = {
    f1,
    f2,
    f3,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    typedef void (*FPTR)();

FPTR const fa[] = { f1, f2};
// fa[1] = f2;  You get compilation error when uncomment this line.
```

Answer (score 2):

Which compiler are you using? This works on VS2005.

```
#include <iostream>

void func1() {std::cout << "func1" << std::endl;}
void func2() {std::cout << "func2" << std::endl;}
void func3() {std::cout << "func3" << std::endl;}

int main()
{
int ret = 0;

typedef void (*FP)();

const FP array[3] = {&func1, &func2, &func3};

return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the array itself to be const:

```
FP const a[] =
    {
        func1,
        func2,
        func3
    };
```

Comment: Whether he writes `FP const` or `const FP` makes no difference. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808471/is-const-lpvoid-equivalent-to-void-const

Comment: @ltib:  While I agree, I'm not sure I see the relevance of your comment.  Perhaps you're just observing, in which case, cheers.

Comment: I was just a bit confused, since your answer and the question are basically identical. Just that your's is a non-member array (and that you have the const at another place). So i'm not seeing the relevance of your answer. But maybe you are just observing likewise, so cheers.