# Understanding pointers in functions

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

so I've been studying pointers, trying to understand them.

I know that in the following line

```
int f(int ni, int n);
```

f is a function that accepts two int variables as its input and it returns an int as the result

If I write the following line

```
int (*f)(int ni, int n);
```

then f is a function pointer

However, what happens when I write something like?

```
int (*f[4])(int p);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use [`cdecl`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28*f%5B4%5D%29%28int%29) for pub quiz questions like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an array of 4 pointers to function, example:

```
int foo(int p) {
    return 0;
}

int (*f[4])(int p);
f[0] = foo;
f[1] = foo;
f[2] = foo;
f[3] = foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to this link :

[Array functions pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200646/how-do-you-declare-a-const-array-of-function-pointers)

There's explainations about what is does and how to implement it