# C++ typedef interpretation of const pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, typedef

Firstly, sample codes:

Case 1:

```
typedef char* CHARS;
typedef CHARS const CPTR;   // constant pointer to chars
```

Textually replacing CHARS becomes:

```
typedef char* const CPTR;   // still a constant pointer to chars
```

Case 2:

```
typedef char* CHARS;
typedef const CHARS CPTR;   // constant pointer to chars
```

Textually replacing CHARS becomes:

```
typedef const char* CPTR;   // pointer to constant chars
```

In case 2, after textually replacing CHARS, the meaning of the typedef changed. Why is this so? How does C++ interpret this definition?

Comment: In general, it is a bad idea to typedef pointers (hiding the star), precisely because const cannot be inserted between the pointed-to-type and the star anymore.

Comment: Sort-of duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808471/is-const-lpvoid-equivalent-to-void-const/1808665

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's no point in analyzing `typedef` behavior on the basis of textual replacement. Typedef-names are not macros, they are not replaced textually.

As you noted yourself

```
typedef CHARS const CPTR;
```

is the same thing as

```
typedef const CHARS CPTR;
```

This is so for the very same reason why

```
typedef const int CI;
```

has the same meaning as

```
typedef int const CI;
```

Typedef-name don't define new types (only aliases to existing ones), but they are "atomic" in a sense that any qualifiers (like `const`) apply at the very top level, i.e. they apply to the *entire* type hidden behind the typedef-name. Once you defined a typedef-name, you can't "inject" a qualifier into it so that it would modify any deeper levels of the type.

Answer (score 14):

Typedef is not a simple textual substitution.

```
typedef const CHARS CPTR;
```

Means "the CPTR type will be a const CHARS thing."  But CHARS is a pointer-to-char type, so this says "the CPTR type will be a const pointer-to-char type." This does not match what you see when you do a simple substituion.

In other words,

```
typedef char * CHARS;
```

is *not* the same as

```
#define CHARS char *
```

The typedef syntax is like a variable declaration, except that instead of declaring the target name to be a variable, it declares it as a new type name which can be used to declare variables of the type that the variable would be without the typedef.

Here's a simple process for figuring out what a typedef is declaring:

1. Remove the `typedef` keyword.  Now you will have a variable declaration.

   ```
   const CHARS CPTR;
   ```
2. Figure out what type that variable is (some compilers have a `typeof()`operator which does exactly this and is very useful). Call that type T.  In this case, a constant pointer to (non-constant) char.
3. Replace the `typedef`.  You  are now declaring a new type (`CPTR`) which is exactly the same type as T, a constant pointer to (non-constant) char.