# What are the rules to typedef and pointers in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ typedef interpretation of const pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253738/c-typedef-interpretation-of-const-pointers)

I just learned that `typedef` does weird things with pointers

Here's an example:

```
typedef float* fptr;
const fptr f; // This is float * const f instead of const float * (like I wanted)
```

Why does it do that?

Comment: How is this "weird"? It does exactly what it says on the tin. It's true that C++ contains "weird stuff", but this is certainly not an example.

Comment: Read what you wrote. `fptr` is what? It is a pointer to float. What do you get when you make that constant? A constant pointer to float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like already answered in :

[C++ typedef interpretation of const pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253738/c-typedef-interpretation-of-const-pointers)

See also [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/typedef-pointers-a-good-idea) for more of a discussion on typedef and pointers.