# Pointer to constant in C

Tags: c

Im having a problem with the pointer to constant. Here are my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _duong                   
{
    int tuoi;
    int chieucao;
}duong;             

struct _duong DUONG;

typedef struct _duong *pduong;

const pduong p;

int main(void)
{
    p = &DUONG;
    p->tuoi = 25;
    p->chieucao = 165;
    printf("tuoi : %d\n",DUONG.tuoi);
    printf("chieucao : %d\n",DUONG.chieucao);
    return 1;
}
```

compiler throw an error: Cannot assign to variable 'p' with const-qualified type 'const pduong'.
I can see that the problem come from

```
const pduong p;
```

and

```
p = &DUONG;
```

for my understanding `const pduong p` is a pointer to constant so that we can not change the value of the pointed variable but we can change the address it point to. So can anyone help me why the compiler showed this error? Thank you.

Comment: Dont typedef pointers, my two minutes are gone....

Comment: It is a constant pointer, not pointer to constant.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253738/c-typedef-interpretation-of-const-pointers

Comment: i know the differences between the constant pointer and pointer to constant, but can you explain more specific for this case, why `const pduong p` here is a constant pointer? @AnT

Comment: @Dương: Follow the link above. Or do a search here. The question has been explained, explained and overexplained many times on SO. Honestly, I'd say that it is you who have to explain first why you expected it to be a pointer to constant. Why really? It is hard to answer your question without understanding the source of your confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And this is one of the reasons why I *strongly* recommend against `typedef`-ing pointer types - the `const` semantics apply to the pointer, not to what is being pointed to.

```
const pduong p;
```

means

```
struct _duong * const p; // p is a const pointer to non-const type
```

not

```
const struct _duong *p;  // p is a non-const pointer to const type
```

In other words, you are declaring `p` as a *const pointer* to `struct _duong`, not as a pointer to `const struct _duong`.

Personally, I would recommend you ditch the `typedef` altogether and declare the pointer explicitly:

```
const struct _duong *p;
```

Typedefs are great for abstracting away details, and `typedef`-ing pointer types is fine *if the user doesn't have to be aware of the "pointer-ness" of the type*.  In this case, the user *does* have to be aware of `p`'s "pointer-ness" to use it correctly, so its type should not be hidden behind a typedef.

Answer (score 2):

No the pointer itself is a constant.

I.e you cannot change the pointer. But whatever that pointer points to you can change.

To correct this change

```
const pduong p;
```

to

```
const pduong p = &DUONG;
```

And then drop the line

```
 p = &DUONG;
```

**EDIT**

Perhaps you want

```
const duong p_contents = {25, 165};
const pduong * const p = &p_contents;
```

Comment: would be worth adding the syntax of a 'pointer to const DUONG` if that's what op really wanted to have

Comment: Add `const pduong const p` as well?

Answer (score 0):

No, the address of a const pointer can't be changed. Only the value it is pointing to.