# Visual Studio C26462 Code Analysis Warning with HWND

Tags: c++, mfc, constants

In a Visual Studio MFC app, I have the following function:

```
BOOL CSomeDialog::OnToolTipNotify(UINT id, NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    ...

    // Get the window handle ...
    const HWND hControl = (HWND)pNMHDR->idFrom;

    ...
}
```

Visual Studio's code analysis reports:

```
Warning C26462  The value pointed to by 'hControl' is assigned only once, mark it as a pointer to const (con.4).
```

I do like code analysis to report on variables that can be consts (I think it clarifies the code's intent), however I don't understand why the above code generates this message. I suspect I am declaring a const pointer rather than a pointer to a const, but I'm unsure of the fix (I've tried "HWND const hControl").

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ typedef interpretation of const pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253738/c-typedef-interpretation-of-const-pointers)

Comment: @GSerg, that's a similar concept (the order of "const" vs the pointer declaration), but it doesn't explain the issue relative to an HWND variable.

Comment: It's not the order of const, it's the fact that `const HWND hControl` is not the same as `const void* hControl`.

Comment: If it was `typedef void* HWND`, a `const HWND` would be a `void* const`, @GSerg. As a side note, that's why I always put the `const` to the right of what is supposed to remain constant, not on the left.

Comment: Can you please extract and provide a [mcve]? I'm not 100% sure that there is something else in the code you don't show that causes these issues. Also, what C++ type does `HWND` eventually resolve to?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would do:

```
#define CHWND const HWND__ * const
CHWND hControl = (CHWND)pNMHDR->idFrom;
```

Alternatively you could this:

```
typedef const HWND__* const CHWND;
CHWND hControl = (CHWND)pNMHDR->idFrom;
```

Or this:

```
using CHWND = const HWND__* const;
CHWND hControl = (CHWND)pNMHDR->idFrom;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. `HWND` is an opaque handle type. Doing it your way would make it impossible to initialize a `HWND` from a `CHWND`. Don't get me started with the `#defined` which is a really bad substitute for a `typedef`, btw.