# Why I cannot `static_cast` from `const char *` to `const PVOID` (`typedef void *`)?

Tags: c++, pointers, static-cast

But `static_cast` from `const char *` to `CPVOID`, which is `typedef const void *`, is seamless.

Is there some difference between `const PVOID` and `CPVOID`, that I don't understand?

Code:

```
typedef void * PVOID;
typedef const void * CPVOID;

int main()
{
    const char * c = nullptr;

    CPVOID e = static_cast<CPVOID>(c);             // Ok
    const PVOID f = static_cast<const PVOID>(c);   // Error
}
```

[Wider example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eca6956ed5ad8ba3)

Comment: `const PVOID` "is" `const (void *)` which is `void * const`, so a constant pointer to void, whereas CPVOID is a pointer to constant void

Comment: [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2253738/1896169) [things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1808471/1896169) that are near duplicates. Together with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143262/1896169), that should complete all the information needed to answer this question